# I can't get Powershell StartsWith function to work

Tags: powershell, startswith

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that prints out only certain AD groups from the Folder Permission settings. However for some reason Powershell doesn't recognize StartsWith function.

```
("C:\folder" | get-acl).Access | ForEach-Object { if (($_.IdentityReference).StartsWith("sl_test")) { continue }; $_ }
```

When I run this I got errors similar to this for every foreach object:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] does not contain a method named 'StartsWith'.
>   At C:\temp\test.ps1:1 char:56
>   + ("C:\folder" | get-acl).Access | ForEach-Object { if (($_.IdentityReference).St ...
>   +                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the string representation of an `IdentityReference` (regardless of whether it's and `NTAccount` object or a SID), you can reference the `Value` property:

```
$_.IdentityReference.Value.StartsWith('sl_test')
```

Answer (score 3):

`IdentityReference` is a `[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]`according to your error message.

But `.StartWith` is a method on the String type. If you call a method, Powershell does no magic for you, AFAIK.

Try `... ($_.IdentityReference) -match "^sl_test" ...`, which should do the implicit string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Get-Acl -Path "C:\folder" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "sl_test*" }
```

You can customize the output with an additional `| Select-Object -Property XY`